# Take the content from first <p>...</p>

Tags: php, regex

I have got field in database with `<p>intro content</p><p>rest of content....</p>`

I would like to take the part from intro content means the content between first `<p>...</p>`

After that I want to remove the intro content `<p>intro content</p>` from the content part.

Could you help me with that?

Comment: Do you want to do something with the text `"intro comment"` from the first set of paragraph tags, or do you just want to remove the first paragraph completely?

Comment: Don't use regexes for stuff like this especially when PHP has powerful classes such as DOMDocument and DOMXpath.

Comment: I want to save "intro comment" in the database in separate field. I would like to remove the "intro comment" from the full_conntent field then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do any kind of parsing on HTML, [you really shouldn't use regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).  However, your question is fairly simple if all you want is the text content of the first `<p>` tag in a string:

```
preg_match('@<p>.*?</p>@', $string, $matches);
```

Comment: Thanks, with your code I will have the content from first p tag. Could you also tell me what should I do to remove first paragraph from the full_article then, becouse I will have it in separate field then. So the question now is how to remove the first parahraph of content from the field (included p tags)?

Comment: Use `preg_replace()`, and specify limit=1.

Comment: Could you give some more details please?